# How to display new line from database to jTable in netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jtable, newline

I'm currently having a problem where my jTable does not read the newline from the database. It just continuously display all the data in one line. It's fine when I'm generating a jasper report though. Here's my code for retrieving the data from the database and displaying it on the table:

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
Connection conn = null;

public void UpdateJTable6(){

    String sql = "SELECT salesID AS 'Sales ID', sales1.clientID AS 'Client ID', customer.firstName AS 'First Name', customer.lastName AS 'Last Name', sales1.productName AS 'Purchased',"
            + " qty AS 'Quantity', qtyTotal as 'Total Quantity',unit AS 'Unit Price', amount as 'Amount', date AS 'Date', total as 'Total Price'"
            + " FROM sales1,customer, products WHERE customer.clientID = sales1.clientID GROUP BY salesID";

try
{
    pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
    jTable6.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));




}catch(Exception e){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);};
```

Here is an example of my table in phpmyadmin. It clearly has a newline in the productName, qty, unit and amount:[image]

Here is the output that the table displays:[image]

Comment: I'd suspect it's a problem in `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)`. What class is that and did you check the resulting table model (e.g. did you step through your code with a debugger)?

Comment: It's just an import from net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

Comment: Well it's not "just an import". It's a class that you are using and that's likely to cause the problems if what you're posted is your actual code and your problem description is accurate. Also "my jTable does not read the newline from the database" is conceptually wrong: the table itself doesn't read from the database but your method `UpdateJTable6()` does (you should check out the Java naming conventions btw) and newlines aren't just "ignored" - assuming you want a table row per resultset row note that newlines are _not_ used to separate rows.

Comment: I don't want a table row per resultset row. My data in one field just contains multiple newlines that the database can certainly read and print in a report. Also I tried to search for the problems with DbUtils regarding newlines and I found nothing. I'm so lost now.

Comment: So _one field_ in _one row_ contains linebreaks that are not displayed correctly? In that case you might want to provide some example, i.e. the input you have (one of those fields), the output you'd expect and the output you'd get (could be screenshots). Besides that it's probably best to just _debug_ your code, i.e. grab the sources of the library you're using, start a debugger and step through your code. And besides that I'm pretty sure the database returns the strings correctly (and the db itself most likely does not create the report but your code or jasper reports does). ...

Comment: ... In fact, it might not even be a problem of reading the data or building the model but how it is displayed (i.e. what the table cell renderer is doing). But to find where it goes wrong you need to debug your code and see where the linebreaks start to go missing.

Comment: I think you're right about the problem is how it is displayed. I already provided the pictures for the input and output in the post (hoping this could help). I tried inputting 3 more newlines in the table from the database itself and the program still continues not to display the newlines

Comment: Well the problem is your SQL. The result of the query is combining all the data into a single row. Get rid of all your "where" and "group by" conditions and see what happens.

Comment: I already tried querying just the productName and it's the same result. Still no newline.

Comment: @camickr if you have a look at the table you'll see that there's just _one_ row and the newlines are _inside_ the fields. That is a problem by itself (it's bad design given that it affects columns like `unit` and `amount` which seem to be coupled) but shouldn't affect how the data is displayed.

Comment: @JoseG. so did you debug your application to make sure the newlines are still in the table model? If so then have a look at how the tables are rendered (the documentation on `JTable` should provide quite a lot hints as to where to look). Assuming you didn't change the defaults the cells are probably rendered by `DefaultTableCellRenderer` which in turn provides a `JLabel` to display each cell. Thus you'd basically have 2 options: make `JLabel` display linebreaks (read the docs) or provide your own custom `TableCellRenderer`.

Comment: @Thomas, I know and that is why I suggested the solution is to  change the SQL then each record will be passed as a single row instead of having merged data with newlines in a single cell.

Comment: @camickr I see and you're basically right. What strikes me odd is the rows that get selected but are not part of the group-by clause. The databases I know normally refuse to group the data that way but I guess MySQL (that's what "phpmyadmin" indicates for me) allows it and displays the data accordingly.